# Binding double click in nested listview

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I've got a ListView nested into another Listview. Now I want to bind an double-click event to the ListViewItems of the inner ListView

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultTemplate">
            <ListView Name="jobsView" ItemsSource="{Binding jobs}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedProduction}" >
                <ListView.InputBindings>
                    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ItemSelectedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=jobsView, Path=SelectedItem}" />
                 </ListView.InputBindings>
             </ListView>
         </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <ListView Name="weekView" ItemsSource="{Binding dayList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}"  >
    </ListView>
</UserControl>
```

I created a RelayCommand called `ItemSelectedCommand` in my ViewModel.

```
public RelayCommand ItemSelectedCommand { get; private set; }
```

The RelayCommand is not getting triggered. I guess I'm setting the wrong RelativeSource. How would it look correct?

Comment: Do you get Error 40 in your Output window?

Comment: No, I receive no errors in the console

Comment: I have a solution for you! You need to set the input binding on the actual item template for your nested ListView. I'll post the solution in a sec.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your ListView inserted. Is there in a Visual Tree a parent with type of `UserControl`?

Also, what's quite good to fix Binding errors is to take a look at the Console. There should be Binding errors that might point you wherte is the mistake. Usually is writes down where it is trying to search for object and property :)

Also, I am not sure if `private get;` is actually allowed when binding to property.

Comment: I receive not binding errors. It's also just private set; get is public. I've updated my question! :)

Comment: Does your UserControl have set `DataContext` to your view model that contains your command?

For me, it looks quite okay. The `RelativeSource` is trying to find a parent with type `UserControl`.

I would try changing private set; to public and setting `DataContext` to your ViewModel :)

Comment: DataCOntext is set `DataContext="{Binding overviewWeek, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"`. I also changed `set` to public but It's still not working

Comment: And the `ICommand` you implemented is on that `overviewWeek` model?

You might also try change the Binding to:

`<MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ItemSelectedCommand, ElementName="jobsView"  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=jobsView, Path=SelectedItem}" />`

Comment: I moved the InputBinding to a Grid inside of hte ListViewItem. Now the Event is getting triggered but the selected item is not getting passed by the call. Do you got an idea to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultTemplate" DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding .}"/>
                    <ListView>
                        <ListView.ItemsSource>
                            <CompositeCollection>
                                <sys:String>Sub Item</sys:String>
                            </CompositeCollection>
                        </ListView.ItemsSource>
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
                                    <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                                        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding DataContext.RenameCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"/>
                                    </TextBlock.InputBindings>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </StackPanel.Resources>

        <ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}">
            <ListView.ItemsSource>
                <CompositeCollection>
                    <sys:String> First Item</sys:String>
                </CompositeCollection>
            </ListView.ItemsSource>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
```

Reason why it wasn't working for you is because the double Click was on an actual ListViewItem and NOT the ListView.